# Q: Remove content using regex

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

Hi i just want to remove content using regex

this is my regex code:

```
reg = reg.replace(/\|.*?(\|)/g, '');
```

**Input:**

```
One-1|two-2|Three-3|Four-4|Five-5

Six-6|Seven-7|Eight-8|Nine|Ten-10

Eleven-11|Twelve-12|Thirteen-13|Fourteen-14|Fifteen-15

Sixteen-16|Seventeen-17|Eighteen-18|Nineteen-19|Twenty-20
```

**Result:**

```
Three-3

Eight-8

Thirteen-13

Eighteen-18
```

**Edited**:
please correct my regex here: https://regex101.com/r/yP3qD9/1 the highlight will be removed..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the below,

```
string.replace(/.*?\|([^|]*)\|[^|]*\|[^|]*$/m, '$1')
```

`m` multiline modifier is  a must need one when,

1. anchors are used in your regex.
2. And the input contain atleast a line break.

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/yP3qD9/2)

Answer (score 0):

I think a array op will be better

```
var string = 'One-1|two-2|Three-3|Four-4|Five-5';
var arr = string.split('|');
var part = arr[Math.floor(arr.length/2)]
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/1p19gb0q/)

---

A regex could look like

```
'One-1|two-2|Three-3|Four-4|Five-5'.replace(/^(.*?\|){2}|(\|[^|]*){2}$/g, '')
```

Demo: [RegEx](https://regex101.com/r/yP3qD9/3)

Comment: hello @Arun here my regex https://regex101.com/r/yP3qD9/1 the matches will be removed..